# SSRS Format to display as percent with 2 decimal places

Tags: reporting-services, format, rounding

I have searched for this issue on stackoverflow, but didn't get what I want

I am doing `a/b` like that in Expr:

```
IF(Sum(Fields!b.Value)=0,0,Sum(Fields!a.Value)/Sum(Fields!b.Value))
```

I have used `P2` inside Textbox Properties Format, but I have the following problem:

3900/20000 = 0.195 * 100 = 19.5 -> The Report display 19.50 - OK

179400/70000            = 256.2857 -> The Report display 256.286 - NOT OK

I need it to display: 256.29

I think doing Round like `Round(x,2)`, but it rounds to 256. It is not what I want

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

First Step go to Textbox Properties
[image]

then:
[image]

Comment: Hi Chiwangc, 

first thanks for help... icannot see this screen in visual studio 2005

i am doing right click on cell -> properties -> i am seeing Format

it seem the screen shoot is different from yours

But i don't see this option 12345,00 !!!
Thanks

Comment: Hi, i'am not  Chiwangc, for the picture it's picked from ssrs 2008 and i have a frensh language in visual studion you can try this :
`Format(Sum(Fields!a.Value)/Sum(Fields!b.Value),"F2")`

Comment: forgive me about my confusing , i need to format with P2 not F2

and that what i did , But somehow :

25.2857 -> The Report display 25.286%

Note: P will add percent (mult the result with 100 and add %)
Thanks a lot

Comment: The issue is still happend  why 25.2857 coverted/displayed like 25.286%

How to round it to display 25.29%

Comment: Round(Sum(Fields!a.Value)/Sum(Fields!b.Value),2)